# R: returning and accessing matrix in vector

Tags: r, matrix, vector, return

so in one of my functions, named `place`, I'm returning a matrix `board`, and a vector `av_targets`.

```
place <- function(ship, orientation, location, board, av_targets){
  if (orientation[1] ==-1){
    for (i in 0:(as.integer(ships_dim[ship])-1)){
      board[location[1],location[2]+(i*as.integer(orientation[2]))]<- keys[ship]
      av_targets <- av_targets[av_targets != paste0(location[1],location[2])]
    }
  }
  if (orientation[1] ==1){
    for (i in 0:(as.integer(ships_dim[ship])-1)){
      board[location[1]+(i*as.integer(orientation[2])),location[2]]<- keys[ship]
      av_targets <- av_targets[av_targets != paste0(location[1],location[2])]
    }
  }
  return(c(board,av_targets))
}
```

I'm then calling place in an assignment, as such, `v <- place("destroyer",c(1,1),c(4,4), computer_board,computer_av_targets)`

but now I'm having troubles accessing the returned `av_targets`. If i do v[2], it returns the second index of the matrix, which is a 10x10 matrix. So I'm not sure how I can retrieve av_targets from what's returned in the function

EDIT: I also need to be able to retrieve the entire matrix form the return statement. So how can i access that. I'm used to python whereby I would just call v[1] and get the matrix, and v[2] would get the av_targets.

Comment: You can try `return(list(board,av_targets))`, list instead of vector. Than try v[[2]]

Comment: I tried v[[1]] and v[[2]], but it still gives me the 1 and 2nd element of the matrix

Comment: I have edited my comment. please try again.

Comment: Ahhh that works thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to return vector with two different data types but vector only stores an atomic datatype of definite class.
In R only List and data frame has the facility to store data with multiple class type.
so instead of:

return(c(board,av_targets))

create a list and return it:

k <- list(board,av_targets)

return k

Comment: One can also try creating class and return it's object directly but that would be unnecessary for this particular problem